# Массовый insert в базу из массива на php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы

Есть массив $data[1] с рандомным количеством значений, либо вообще пустой.

```
Array
(
    [0] => wRb
    [1] => TxR
    [2] => bw
    [3] => owT
    [4] => hwi
    [5] => hhb
)
```

Как его вставить в таблицу одним запросом, чтобы каждое значение вставлялось в новую строку?
Что-то вроде такого, только заранее неизвестно сколько всего данных в массиве.

```
id(int)   data

1         wRb
2         TxR
3         bw
...       ...
79        owT
80        hwi
```

Comment: Либо через `foreach`, одиночными запросами, либо через мультивставку `VALUES`.

Comment: через `foreach` перебираете массив - создаёте запрос (строку..) `insert into table (data) values ('data1'),('data2')...,('dataN')` и после цикла выполняете запрос

Comment: @InDevX, зачем там форыч, если тут банально надо просто собрать в 1 строчку. Форыч не нужен для объединения в одну мультивставку `VALUES` По этому я и сказал, либо-то, либо-то.

Comment: @And так это зависит от массива с данными, в одном случае хватит и join'а, в другом уже маловато будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы собрать в один запрос, нужно воспользоваться функцией `join`.
И просто правильно разобрать:

```
$arr = [
    0 => "a",
    1 => "b",
    2 => "c"
];

$values = "INSERT INTO `table` (`data`) VALUES ('" . join("'), ('", $arr) . "')";
```

В результате получим:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`data`) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')
```

По хорошему, если будет много столбцов и разные данные, можно сделать, чтобы массив выглядел так: `column => value` где ключ столбец, а значение массива, для вставки в столбец.

Comment: только надо быть аккуратнее с данными, вдруг в них одинарные кавычки попадутся ... стоит их заэкранировать

Comment: @Mike, Я понятия не имею, что он там делает и какую архитектуру базы использует, это все в подготавливаемых запросах можно сделать, по этому смысла нет суда это лепить.

Comment: при обучении, т.е. как раз в ответах, упоминать стоит, что бы люди задумывались хотя бы о возможности подобных проблем